# Wireless USB adapter on 10.04

Tags: 10.04, wireless, usb, wireless-access-point, adapter

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm trying to follow the guide posted by Matt:
http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc

But I don't know where to enter the following:

```
CONFIG_ATH_COMMON=m
CONFIG_ATH9K_HW=m
CONFIG_ATH9K_COMMON=m
CONFIG_ATH9K_HTC=m
```

Those need to be enabled in the kernel config.  Anyone know how to do that?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have searched on this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsNetgear#USB

But it does not list the WNDA3200, however it does list the WNDA3100.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have been given a wireless USB adapter by my ISP.

After plugging the device in, it does not appear in the NetworkManager Applet.

So I tried `lsusb` and I got this:

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:20ff Atheros Communications, Inc.`

What needs to be done for me to use this wireless USB adapter?

The wireless USB adapter is an:

Netgear Wireless 11N Dual Band USB Adapter WNDA3200

I am using an up-to-date install of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, but check out this page: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc  You will have to compile from source and insert the compiled module [driver].

Comment: Please see update 2 above.

Comment: Posted as an answer, please tell me if it works.  As long as your system is set up to compile, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the more modern wireless cards and drivers I would recommend you install the 2.6.38 kernel which is now available from the standard Lucid repositories - it is now supported by Canonical.

**To install:**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

If you are using any proprietary graphics drivers, you will need to reinstall these from the *Hardware Drivers* window.

N.B. you may also need to install the [x-updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) for updated graphics drivers i.e.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However I would recommend an drive image backup first to allow you to get to a clean start point.

**To remove:**

If you find yourself without a bootable computer, press and hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button during the boot sequence and you will be able to select the older 2.6.32 kernel.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

If you also had installed x-updates then

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Comment: installing asked 208mb free space, uninstalling asked to remove 56kb also got this error http://pastebin.com/y3qDDTnc ppa-purge doesn't work but i don't know if i installed "x-updates"

Comment: and it didn't uninstall it was still here and im still getting errors in 32-37

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu thinks its a virtual cdrom until you run the eject command. If you run `lsusb`, it will show you different info afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the `ath9k_htc` driver.
Here's an easy way to install it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ath9k-htc/

Once you've installed that the installer should be in *Applications -> System tools*.
[image: Screenshot taken from the SourceForge page]

---

Might be good to warn you that you'll probably have to run the installer again every time you update your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Download compat-wireless .tar file, and untar.

`tar xf compat-wireless*`

then cd

`cd compat-wireless-2011*`

then select your driver

`./scripts/driver-select ath9k_htc`

then compile

`make`

then copy your driver to your home folder:

`cp ./drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko  ~/ath9k_htc.ko`

then insert it into the kernel

`insmod ~/ath9k_htc.ko`

Your wireless should now work!  Just a heads up, you have to do this every time after you boot.  Put this in a bash script, make it executable, then add it to your *Startup Applications*